# How to create dialogue in a book?

Tags: dialogue

This question may sound strange to you, but I am starting to write my book for the first time, so I hope that everyone will understand me. My question is that I do not know how to write the dialogue correctly. How to write the dialogue of the main characters? And how to write ordinary dialogues, for example:

> Did "name" go to work today?

Please help with the question. I will be very grateful

Comment: Are you writing in Russian or Ukrainian? The formatting rules will be different from English in those languages. See for example: https://www.reddit.com/r/russian/comments/2t9cdb/how_do_you_write_and_punctuate_dialogue_in_russian/ I think you should search for that information in the language you are writing in.

Answer (score 0):

It might vary depending on the language you intend to write for, but these are general rules I wrote (Tumblr blog) on how to edit dialog since I found a lot of advice to be pedantic and not useful.:
https://www.tumblr.com/kimyoonmiauthor/640219855878045696/how-to-improve-dialogue?source=share

The article is rather long and I did link general tips.

I tried my best to write tips that you can vary based on the language used.

For example, Japanese, and Korean are more intuitive languages and contextually-based, therefore, more under dialogue is needed in order to write those languages and the translation of them somewhat too.

But your biggest tool in any language (And I say this knowing and watching a bunch of different movies in different languages and reading literature across different countries) is the art of deletion. While some languages, say Chinese as said by Chinese speakers is more literal in some ways compared to English (though there is a huge poetic streak), it still uses the art of deletion in dialogue.

The more you're able to delete artfully with dialogue, the more artful you'll look as a writer.

The art of deletion is where you indicate something based on a prior relationship, and this comes into play particularly with things like banter and arguing. Banter arguing is probably one of the hardest skills to master, because you need to have a really good sense of character(s), the character's relationships to everything, and have quick, witty returns.

Someone requested a guide for that, too, so I also wrote one for that:
https://www.tumblr.com/kimyoonmiauthor/719573024836321280/how-to-write-banter?source=share

And banter is something you just need to practice with real humans to get. If anyone wants to do a banter off, I can do one.

I also did a dialogue analysis and weaknesses analysis of a particular episode.

https://www.tumblr.com/kimyoonmiauthor/662278268792258560/dialogue-analysis-from-titans-season-3-episode-7?source=share

So, if you have say, a mother and her daughter and say, the daughter is going out, it doesn't sound like this:

"Mother, I am leaving for school right now and I might be home for dinner. I will call you to pick me up. Is that fine?"

"Casey, that sounds very good. I hope you did your homework. I will come pick you up when you call me."

Does not sound natural at all in any language I know.

Something like,
"Mom, School. Later."

"Yeah, Casey, did you do your homework?"

"Yeah, yeah, whatever, Mom."

"You better have done it. Call me and I'll pick you after work."

And notice the deletion there. It's much shorter because the characters know each other more and have an established relationship. But once you get the art of deletion, then you can pick up other techniques to refine it further.